# Firebase authentication using token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I want to add security to my firebase application so that no one can write data by only knowing firebase url. We are using Android/ iOS client applications and php server.
 I need the following to be clarified.

1. Is authentication using token is the best way to add security (we do not need a user login)
2. I do not want the token to be expired. Is this possible?
3. Will this effect read operations from client apps which do not use this tokens?
4. Can I remove this authentication later so that any one can access

Comment: In the future, please ask one question at a time. It's a Q&A forum and asking several questions makes it extremely difficult to judge the "correct" answer or "best" answer, since there may be several to each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase uses a declarative, server-side rules language to control access to data. This is covered in detail in the [security docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/). I'd highly recommend reading this before continuing; it would address all the questions here and save some pain later.

Authentication is indeed the simplest way to identify users and control access. Firebase provides a number of authentication methods, including [Anonymous auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/anonymous.html).

Since security rules can also depend on data stored in Firebase, and use a complex rules engine, it's possible to create any sort of dynamic combination of authenticated and non-authenticated access, role-based security, et al.